# Set classPath for java

Tags: android

I am trying to run the draw9patch.bat from my cmd but it throws the following error.

```
           WARNING: Java not found in your path.
           Checking if it's installed in C:\Program Files\Java instead (64-bit).
           Checking if it's installed in C:\Program Files\Java instead.

           ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
           Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
           We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
           http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

          You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
          http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

I have java installed and have also tried changing the classpath from environment variables in the control panel.However it does not seem to solve the problem.What am i doing wrong.

Comment: might be using older version of java .

Comment: Have you set your JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to set the 'path' environment variable.

Something like this:

```
path=%path%;c:\program files\java\jdk 1.6\bin
```

or 
the path where you have installed the java.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the swing-worker-1.1.jar,  place this in Android-sdk/tools/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are looking for solution for Windows 7 (maybe for xp too) and that last answers wasn't the right solution.
If you have problem with running this file, this problem will happens in almost all .bat files in `android-sdks/tools` files.

Here is what to do and all that batch files will work okay.
I assume that you have downloaded proper JDK so..

Go to folder `android-sdks\tools\lib` and edit file `find_java.bat`
Delete all text stored inside and insert into something like that:

```
set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
if not defined java_exe goto :CheckFailed

:SearchJavaW
set javaw_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"
if not exist %javaw_exe% set javaw_exe=%java_exe%
goto :EOF
```

Please be carefull and put correct path to jre what you have! Here is an example for jre7!